# error in build cas (SSO) apereo

Tags: java, single-sign-on, cas

I'm trying to build CAS server from source and run step by step by url 
[Build Process](https://apereo.github.io/cas/developer/Build-Process-5X.html)

I get this error in step  build:

`./gradlew build install --parallel -x test -x javadoc -x check`

Error Message:

> An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_66). Please file a
>   bug at the Java Bug Database (http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/)
>   after checking the database for duplicates. Include your program and
>   the following diagnostic in your report.  Thank you.
>
> Task :api:cas-server-core-api-webflow:compileJava
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.sun.tools.javac.util.JavacMessages.add(Lcom/sun/tools/javac/util/JavacMessages$ResourceBundleHelper;)V

Answer (score 1):

If you cloned the master branch, you need at least JDK10 today. If you clone the 5.3.x or 5.3.x branches, you can use JDK 8. Check the gradle.properties for the required JDK version.